# Why EF migrations adds field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I use Identity 2.0. I have `CustomUserRole`

```
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
}
```

When i try generate a migration all is good. But if i add a configuration to `CustomUserRole`

```
 public class CustomRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleConfiguration()
        {
            Property(r => r.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        }
    }
```

EF adds a field `CustomRole_Id`

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    CustomRole_Id = c.Long(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CustomRoles", t => t.CustomRole_Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.CustomRole_Id);
```

Now i have two field for `Role`. I dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write

```
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

after

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DocumentConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubvisionConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DocumentActionConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomRoleConfiguration());
```

while i write it before